# Query Didn't Count number who has value >= 10, VB.NET 2010, MS.Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, count

So i had a table with a bunch of numbers, i want to count how much number has value less or more than 
x number and then display it in Form on VB.net 2010, it goes well until the numbers have value of ten(10) or higher, the query somehow didn't count the numbers, but when i change the numbers to 9, the count works

here's my code :

```
    cmd9 = New OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM data_ukm where hasil = 'TUNDA' and jml_aset < '5' ", Conn)
    tunda1.Text = cmd9.ExecuteScalar.ToString <<~~ the numbers 10 or higher count as '< 5' numbers

    cmd10 = New OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM data_ukm where hasil = 'TUNDA' and jml_aset > '4' and jml_aset < '8' ", Conn)
    tunda2.Text = cmd10.ExecuteScalar.ToString

    cmd11 = New OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM data_ukm where hasil = 'TUNDA' and jml_aset > '7' ", Conn)
    tunda3.Text = cmd11.ExecuteScalar.ToString <<~~ the numbers 10 or higher should be count to this label
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the data type of `jml_aset` is `TEXT` although you want it to be treated as a number.
When you make text comparisons then `'2'` is greater than `'10'` because what happens is char by char comparison between the 2 strings and `'2'` is greater than `'1'`.
The best thing to do is change the data type of `jml_aset` to an integer `Number` or do the comparisons like:

```
val(jml_aset) > 7
```

Comment: i changed the type of jml_aset and it works , thanks for th help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are treating your numbers as text. In text form, '10' is less than '2' just as 'ba' is less than 'c'. Just as you put double quotes around text but not numbers in VB, so you put single quotes around text but not numbers in SQL. Make sure that your column is a numeric type as well.

Comment: i changed the type of jml_aset and it works , thanks for th help :)